# Adding a custom control in visual web part

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone please provide steps or a link for deploying a visual webpart with custom control in sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anand,

Register the control at the top your Visual Web Part ascx file with Register tag:

```
<%@ Register 
TagPrefix="demo" 
Namespace="ControlsDemo" 
Assembly="ControlsDemo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=01374ea14aa626aa" %>
```

where Namespace should be namespace of the control's class file.. You can get the PublicKeyToken by using Visual Studio Command Prompt and writing following command:

```
sn –T "Complete dll path"
```

Once you registered the control, you can use in your Visual Web Part as follows:

```
<demo:ServerNameControl runat="server" id="serverNameControl"/>
```

PS: Please follow Kirk Evan's following post
[User Controls and Server Controls in SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/28/user-controls-and-server-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx)